# hive regexp_replace remove multiple strings

Tags: hive

In my data i have strings that have special characters

```
&#39, &amp; &quot,
```

is there a way to use regexp_replace to replace multiple strings. Even better is there a way to select 'test_column' and if there are weird characters(etc. &) to remove them. In my query i am using

```
select regexp_replace(test_column, "(&#39)|(&amp;)","'| &") as my_column
```

This is not doing what i intend it to do. everywhere it finds the weird characters it replaces it with

```
'|&
```

Is there a way to catch and change all of these using a select statement or how can i correctly use regexp_replace on multiple strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your replacement string is `'| &` and hence everything is getting replaced with that string.

```
regexp_replace(string INITIAL_STRING, string PATTERN, string REPLACEMENT)
```

Try this

```
select regexp_replace(test_column, "(&#39)|(&amp;)|(&quot,)","") as my_column
```